# SqlBulkCopy importing time field from Excel as datetime column

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datetime

I've searched far and wide for an answer, but couldn't quite get what I need, so here I go:

I have a couple of Excel files. I need to import them into a SQL Server table. All files, but one are imported ok(I used C# in a small windows forms application).

The problem is there are two time columns in the .xlsx files. In Excel, their format is set to `General` for the files, that import fine.

For the problematic file, the format is set to `Time`. This results in the times being imported as datetime into SQL Server with a fixed date of 1899 30 12, appended to the actual time. Mind you, I have tried changing format to `General`, but that produces floats, that get imported as floats into SQL Server.

The destination SQL Server column is `nvarchar(255)` (don't even get me started about the DB design, it's out of my control to change it, sadly).

I don't know where to look, anymore (is it an Excel formatting issue, is it some invisible casting in the code....)

This is my code:

```
public string bulkInsertFile(string file)
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+file+";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'"))
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Data$]", con);
        OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sql"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlcon))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("start_time", "start_time");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("end_time", "end_time");
            }
        }
    }
    dr.Close();
    dr.Dispose();
    return "Upload Successfull!";
}
```

Comment: are the excel sheets large enough to use `SqlBulkCopy`? suggest read into memory first then use ordinary insert statements.

Comment: Well, the biggest one is 100801 Rows, the smallest- 2000

Comment: I always BulkCopy into a temporary table and then run `insert into select` to do whatever cleanup necessary. Have saved me a lot of troubles like this.

Comment: Well, I solved my issue with some Excel manipulation (I'm not very proud of it, but it gets the job done :D). I Inserted new columns, set the values for their cells to be a formula, that takes the value of the corresponding cell with the time, and makes it a text. After that I did a copy/paste in place, to remove the references, so I could delete the old columns. I don't know if i should post it as an answer, as it is rather a workaround.